# How does 'display' property of svg element affect mouse events?

Tags: css, svg, mouseevent

I have html code like this

```
<svg style="display:block">
</svg>
```

The problem is that svg element can NOT capture mouse events.
Other display properties like 'inline-block', ... cause same effect.
With 'inline' property, it can capture mouse events.
I want to know why and how to fix it.
Try this for easy to understand

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onmousedown="alert('body')">
<svg style="display:block" width="300" height="300" onmousedown="alert('svg1')"></svg>
<svg width="300" height="300" onmousedown="alert('svg2')"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hopefully someone else will be able to answer the main q, but depending upon your end aim, I wonder if a workaround could be something like filling it with a white rect the same size ? So something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5hd6D/

Comment: Thank you! I've solved my problem but I still want to know the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only the case in Chrome and Opera due to a bug in Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=379299 (If you check another browser such as Firefox, you'll see that it does in fact work as expected.)

The fix [has been committed to the master branch](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=175528), and should be live in stable versions of these browsers within a couple months (~end of summer 2014).

In the meantime, you may be able to work around this (depending on your use case) by wrapping the `<svg>` in a `display: block` container element.